# Airflow Maintenance: Killing Empty DAGs

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I've noticed that occasionally my Airflow (in Kubernetes) instance needs to be restarted and I have a process to kill and redeploy, however, I have noticed that DAGs will get caught in a running state with no tasks deployed. What this does is prevent future tasks from being scheduled. I'd like to look into a process that kills DAGs "marked as Failed" when they have zero tasks queed/scheduled.

Has anyone done something like this? I see this link https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags
has a couple processes that I've actaully deployed already (such as killing halted tasks and killing stalled pods).

Thanks